# Shower waste, water level

Tags: water, shower, drain

My shower drain is regularly filling up and overflowing, subsequently leaking water outside of the screened shower area. When not in the shower I removed the tile and waste plate and can see the water level sits at approx 2 inches from the top of the floor level tiles, so when I have shower on full pressure, the water is not escaping quick enough.

I know the waste should not be dry, but could there be a blockage further down the pipe? My shower is on the second floor of my house, so the pipes bend and then go down downstairs, there is a waste cap, then the pipe goes outside.

A few sinks follow this route and they are not blocking, only the shower waste. Please offer advice as to what the problem could be, or if I should poke a hose down to try and unblock? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like the drain is clogged.  Often hair and soap combine to form a messy glob.  Did you try a snake down the drain to clear it out?

Comment: How powerful is your shower ? Basic physics suggest if you have a power shower outputting 100l / min but your waste is only capable of 20l / min the shower will always win.

Comment: This sounds like an entirely routine **clogged drain**.  Sounds like the concept is new to you.  The water a couple inches below the shower drain is a thing called a **trap**, which is a plug of water in a U-shaped pipe.  Your sink has one too. Every drain  has one, or else sewer gas will come up.  It does not impede flow.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica for all we know the OP could have the waste run in 32mm that’s not adequate for a power shower. As the other sinks don’t block it’s unlikely to be a blocked drain, however the blockage could be somewhere above the other waste outlets

Comment: You've never had one drain block and not others @DanK? Happens all the time to me.  It simply means the blockage is *before* the pipes merge.  That's good news, it means it's closer and easier to reach.   I had written off the idea of "built this way" because that would've come up the first time the shower was tested, and the builder would've had to correct it under warranty. If this is a recent modification I'd have expected OP to have said so.